# How do I call a FrontController from within a module

Tags: prestashop

I implemented a Prestashop module for Payment
beside of my main Module I generated a **ModuleFrontController** , which work fine and I have access on it by using URL like **mydomain.com/module/controllers/mymethod**

The problem is I would like to execute this method from my main module class / a simple php file
But I can not find a solution for that yet.

Note :

- I Can not use CURL / open_socket
- I can not call this URL from an Ajax

Simply I want to make an instance of my FrontController and call a method

Any Idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Include that controller file where you want to use and create instance of class and call desired method on that

Answer (score 0):

FrontController define like this :

class ModulenameControllernameModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
...
}

and make didn't accept like normal instance to call $obj = new Classname()
,... or when some how make an instance , wasn't work well. was missing some parameters in $this->context->XXX

Any way my problem solve some have different without need to make an instance .

But I think should be another way like how Cron execute
Ex. for Cron can send parameter like :

```
$_GET['fc'] = 'module';
$_GET['module'] = 'modulename';
$_GET['controller'] = 'controllername';
,....
```

Some how to call FrontController , independently